# Functions that are interpolated in css calls will be stringified

Tags: reactjs, emotion-js

I have this code and I have this error message and whatever I change made, error doesn't go away.

```
const track = css`
  background: ${({ theme }) => rgba(theme.colors.gray['000'], 0.25)};
`
```

Functions that are interpolated in css calls will be stringified.
If you want to have a css call based on props, create a function that returns a css call like this
let dynamicStyle = (props) => css`color: ${props.color}`
It can be called directly with props or interpolated in a styled call like this
let SomeComponent = styled('div')`${dynamicStyle}`

Can anybody explain what is the issue here? and solution?
Existing solutions which can be found in Google for this error doesn't work.

Comment: The error message is the solution.

Comment: @windowsill can you change it from the error message please?

Comment: this has a lot of examples https://emotion.sh/docs/theming

Comment: @windowsill yes I tried them and it still give me error. Why don't you give me update? instead of the documentation link?

Comment: None of those examples have interpolated strings in them. The error you're getting it because of the usage of an interpolated string.

Comment: Yes, can you fix it please? Instead of general guideline can you fix?